# How to get the unique length of a column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the csv data:

```
staff_id,clock_time,device_id,latitude,longitude
1003,2020/8/27 2:55,d_8,26.39899424,117.7866387
1003,2020/8/26 7:45,d_8,26.39900029,117.7866379
1003,2020/8/26 3:09,d_8,26.40672436,117.8008659
1003,2020/8/26 0:26,d_8,26.89169118,117.1612365
1234567,2020/8/25 9:38,d_8,26.89764297,117.1760012
123456789,2020/5/19 8:29,d_8,24.47420087,118.1085551
1003,2020/5/18 9:06,d_8,24.473124,118.1705641
1003,2020/5/16 7:54,d_8,24.5101858,117.8954614
```

I use this code to get the `staff_id` unique length in the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'for_test.csv', encoding='utf-8',parse_dates=[1])
staff_id_list = df.staff_id.values.tolist()
staff_id_length_list = [len(str(item)) for item in staff_id_list]
staff_id_length_list = list(set(staff_id_length_list))
print(staff_id_length_list)
```

The output is :`[9, 4, 7]`

Although the output is correct, I want to use the pandas method to get the length instead of the python method.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) with [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
a = df.staff_id.astype(str).str.len().unique()
print (a)
[4 7 9]
```

If need list:

```
L = df.staff_id.astype(str).str.len().unique().tolist()
print (L)
[4, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.Series.astype` with `str.len` and `unique`:

```
df["staff_id"].astype(str).str.len().unique()
```

Output:

```
array([4, 7, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
df['len'] = df['staff_id'].str.len().drop_duplicates()
```